# for loop to print the integer array in reverse

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program for creating a for loop to print the integer array in reverse order.

```
public class RevIntArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int var[]=new int[3];
        int i;
        for(i = -3; i > -3; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not receiving any results. Can someone provide a simple solution to this?

Comment: Because in the first iteration `i` is not `>-3` the loop instantly stops. As a side note, you are not doing anything with that array...

Comment: -3 > -3 ?! No!! so i > -3 wouldnt be true and it wouldnt enter your loop

Comment: Please don't downvote this. The OP has showed some effort at the least.

Answer (score 5):

arrays have no concept of negative indices, if you want to traverse from the last to first then you must START at the LAST index and move to the FIRST.

```
for(i =3; i>0; i--){

   System.out.println(var[i - 1]);

}
```

Comment: I tried adding it.. But i get 0 0 0 as output..

Comment: @user3220565 You never put any values in your array. Int array values default to 0.

Comment: @user3220565 You could always look at my answer below. ;)

Comment: ^^yes^^.  I was just showing you the problem with your loop.  If your array contains data then it would work.  In addition to that you may want to take the advice of others and use .length instead of hard coding the size of "i" to 3.

Comment: Studpid me.. I didn't add any values in the array.. That was the mistake.. Its working now.. I got the values in reverse.. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: @user3220565 If the answer helped you, don't forget to select it. Use the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

You were starting with a negative index which does not exist in arrays. It's also good practice to use `array.length` instead of an explicit number in case you change the size of the array later on.

```
public class RevIntArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int var[] = new int[] {1,2,3};
        for(int i = var.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            System.out.println(var[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comment for the downvote maybe?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the array has no values to actually see it being reversed.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but there's not much to comment, though you could move the `.length` out of the loop.

Comment: @asgs Why would you remove the length and prefer an explicit number?

Comment: I would prefer length.

Comment: I didn't say I'd remove it. It's just that you could calculate the `i` upfront and store in a local variable.

Comment: I still don't see why you would ever want to do that.

Comment: Because I don't see a need to check the length in every iteration when the array is going to be of fixed size. It's not like a performance improvement or something, it makes your code look clean.

Comment: premature nano-optimization much?

Comment: This does not check the length every iteration. The first part of a for loop is evaluated once. Only the comparison and the increment/decrement are seen each iteration.

Comment: There you go. For once I thought you were doing `var.length - 1 > 0` in the condition part.

Comment: Code is precise, be sure to look at it precisely :)

Comment: Yup, my mistake. I'm glad I didn't downvote you, otherwise I'd have basked in the hall of shame.

Comment: It happens. Thanks for replying and working it out :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of hints to get you going:

```
for(i =-3; i>-3; i++){    
    System.out.println(i);    
}
```

- The values in `var`, being `int`, will be all zeroes (due to the default initialization of the `int` primitive type). Give your array some values so you can effectively check that you're printing it in reverse (for example `var[2] = 1`). Otherwise, make it explicit with `{0,0,1}`).
- Your iteration is wrong. If the size is three, don't start from -3. Even if you got the loop to work, negative indexes are invalid for an array.
- The condition isn't met to begin with, so your `for` is pointless as it is.
- Think about what you're trying to do: Iterating "the other way around" means *starting from the end* and going back to the beginning. You want to start in the last element and go back to index `0`.
- Once you're done with the loop, printing `i` will show the index, not the element. You want the value stored in `var` for that index.
- `i--` will decrease your counter.
- `var.length` will tell you the size of the array. Remember the indexes start on zero, so `length - 1` is the index of the last element.
- To obtain the value stored in a certain position of an array do `array[index]`.

With that in mind, try again.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should provide some values to your array:

`int[] var = { 1, 2, 3 };`

Then, you should initialize your loop counter. You can do this inside the loop structure. Now for the loop:

```
for (int i = var.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    System.out.println(var[i]);
}
```

This should print *321* to the console.